# What publicly accessible tall buildings are good for views & photography in South Los angeles

Tags: california, photography, southern-california

I work in Carson CA and want to find all the best viewpoints in buildings or parks that I can get to in 30 minutes or so.

What publicly accessible tall buildings are good for views & photography in South Los angeles?

Answer (score 1):

USC - kinda. Not too many tall buildings but Mudd Hall may be accessible (South end of campus).  Also some buildings in VKC (Von Kleinsmid Center) in center of campus could work. The Leavey Library too.

Aside from that..Watts Towers? Isn't so tall nor towering, but is a photogenic place.

South LA isn't called the flatlands for nothing ...